# Implicitly-generated constructors with explicit declaration of destructor

Tags: c++11, default-constructor, default-copy-constructor

The thing is, 4th edition of C++ Programming language says:

*In this particular case, if you forgot to delete a copy or move operation, no harm is done. A
move operation is not implicitly generated for a class where the user has explicitly declared a destructor.
**Furthermore, the generation of copy operations is deprecated in this case (§44.2.3).** This
can be a good reason to explicitly define a destructor even where the compiler would have implicitly
provided one (§17.2.3).*

I've tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {
public:
    ~Foo() {}
}
int main() {
    Foo x;
    Foo y(x);
    return 0;
}
```

and there is no errors and exeptions here. I know that copy constructor should be generated implicitly in c++98, but 4th says that copy is deprecated. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that an implicitly-declared constructor is not necessary implicitly-defined.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) :

> **Implicitly-declared copy constructor**
>   If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class.
>
> **Implicitly-defined copy constructor**
>   If the implicitly-declared copy constructor is neither deleted nor trivial, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and compiled) by the compiler if odr-used.
>   *The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor* or user-defined copy assignment operator.

So in your case, the copy constructor is implicitly-declared but not implicitly-defined if not odr-used, which basically means it is not defined unless required somewhere.

See also : [What is the distinction between implicitly-declared and implicitly-defined copy constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149463/what-is-the-distinction-between-implicitly-declared-and-implicitly-defined-copy)

Comment: Thank you, Nelxiost